# Elastic Beanstalk continue after deploy error or retry failed command, must be a simple way to do this

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, deployment, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

So I'm having an issue during deployment where one of the commands in ebextensions fails and stops the deploy process. Is there a way to stop the error from stopping the whole deployment?

More Details

- command is run using an .ebextensions/*.config file

More More Details

- Using t2.micro and running webpacker compile using bundle, because of the limited ram webpacker fails alot but i can usually login and rerun the command from ssh and it works fine.
- So my solution is rerun the command 3 or 4 times during deployment which will resolve the issue, so I just want a way to prevent the command failure from stopping deployment

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to stop the error from stopping the whole deployment?

I think `ignoreErrors` in [commands](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html#linux-commands) should do what you are trying to achieve:

- ignoreErrors - A boolean value that determines if other commands should run if the command contained in the command key fails (returns a nonzero value). Set this value to true if you want to continue running commands even if the command fails. Set it to false if you want to stop running commands if the command fails. The default value is false.

However, I would rather recommend investigating why the command fails, and fixing it, rather than ignoring its errors.